# Kivy: How to populate a nested recycle view, which is inside popup with Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have been trying to get this to work for two days and I cannot find similar issues or documentation that could help. Basically I am making a webcrawler which does some sentiment analysis. Once analysis is complete, a recycleview widget (on a new screen) is used to display this output. (results here is a list of objects returned from another function)

```
class RV(RecycleView):
    data = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        dictList = []
        count = 0
       for company in results:
            entry = {'companyName': company.company_name, 'microAvg': "Micro: " + str(company.micro_average),
            'macroAvg': "Macro: " + str(company.macro_average), 'popup': company.company_name,
            'sentences': (company.sentence_list),'index': count}
            count += 1
            dictList.append(entry)

        self.data = dictList # Populating RV from results


    def message_box(self, message):
        p = MessageBox()
        p.popup = x.popup
        p.second = x.popup

        p.open()
        print('test press: ', message)
```

There is an option here to view more information about a selected company, which should show a list of sentences in a popup, which also uses a recyclerview (which seems to be the only way to represent list items?)to display this list. My issue here is I cannot for the life of me get the second recycler to access the information for the row in which it is supposed to belong. In my latest attempt, I have tried to use a class wide attribute. (PopRV is the smaller second nested recycleview).

```
class PopRVRow(BoxLayout):
    first = StringProperty()
    second = StringProperty()
    sentences = StringProperty()
```

class PopRV(RecycleView):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(PopRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    #self.data = [{'first':str(x)} for x in range(1,10)]
    #self.data = [{'first': str(x)} for x in sentences1]
    self.data = RV.data
```

I have tried to use inheritance, I have tried and failed to use the Kivy widget tree hierarchy, and I have tried to use global variables to achieve this. I am flummoxed.

I should also state that I am a beginner and so it's likely I have not gotten good enough comprehension to debug this.

I have had various errors while trying to complete this depending on my approach, though I have been able to display a list of integers within the PopRV, so it is mostly a matter of getting that data to communicate with the class I think.

```
<RecycleViewRow>:
orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: root.companyName
    Button:
        text: 'More info'
        on_press: app.root.message_box(root.popup)
    Label:
        text: root.microAvg
    Label:
        text: root.macroAvg

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'RecycleViewRow'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'

<OutputWindow>
    name: "output"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RV: # HERE IS THE FIRST RECYCLEVIEW!
        Button:
            text: 'Previous screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 50
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "analysis"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<PopRVRow>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
Label:
    text: root.first
Label:
    text: root.second

<PopRV>:
    viewclass: 'PopRVRow'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

If anyone can help me, I would be incredibly grateful!

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple things here.

- data is already declared as a list property on RecycleView, you don't want to redefine it as an empty list in your class, it's going to break some logic (remove the `data = []` line)
- RecycleView is not the only way to display items, you can always create/update/delete your own widgets manually, but RV saves you a lot of work, so it's best to use it, especially if you can have a lot of items, for performance reasons.
- How is the popup supposed to know which row it's supposed to display? it seems that you want to give it access to the data from the RV instance (inheritance won't help there) but you don't want to display all the rows, only the one the user clicked, right? and you have this information when the user clicks, it so why not pass these values directly to your Popup class and make the popup class pass it to the PopRV instance inside, or at least pass it a reference to the data, and the index its supposed to display?

Some way to do it (i generated fake data, but you should be able to adapt to your use case).

Passing the index (idx) can be useful if you want to edit the data from the popup, as you then only need a reference to the recycleview data to update the content at this position in it.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import DictProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty


KV = '''
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory

<Row@Button>:
    idx: 0
    on_press:
        rv = self.parent.parent
        item = rv.data[self.idx]
        popup = F.DataPopup(title=item['text'], sentences=item['sentences'], target_idx=self.idx)
        popup.open()

<PopupRVRow@Label>:

<DataPopup>:
    # auto_dismiss: False
    target_idx: 0
    target_rv: None
    size_hint: .5, .5

    RecycleView:
        data: [{'text': sentence} for sentence in root.sentences]
        viewclass: 'PopupRVRow'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            default_size: 0, 30

FloatLayout:
    RecycleView:
        data:
            [
            {
            'idx': num,
            'text': str(num) + (chr(num) * (num % 10)),
            'sentences': ['sentence %s %s' % (num, num2) for num2 in range(13, 128)]
            }
            for num in range(127)
            ]

        viewclass: 'Row'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            default_size: 0, 30
'''

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


class DataPopup(Popup):
    sentences = ListProperty()
    target_idx = NumericProperty()
    target_rv = ObjectProperty()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

Comment: TShirtman, you are a legend.

I am currently trying to integrate your code, but after changing the first recycle view (which works, I am getting an error 'Exception: ScrollView accept only one widget' when I press on a button. I have tried to google this but nothing seems relevant to what I am doing. 

Just for reference, I am opening the first RV in a new window/screen, so perhaps that is where it is not happy ? 
Thanks again !

Comment: i don't know exactly what you did but maybe you tried to open the popup on the scrollview instead of the window (which is what happens if you call it without arguments), so if you did something like popup.open(scrollview) just don't, but that's my only guess.

Comment: Ahh god :( I dont have scrollview anywhere but I will continue trying ! Thanks again!

Comment: Managed to fix it - For anyone else that comes across this thread: I was trying to add a button or label  to recycle view at the wrong indentation and the error message just assumed that it was a scrollview

Comment: that's because RecycleView is a subclass of ScrollView.